# Execute Selenium WebDriver script on android phone

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a `Selenium` script to automate the web site on any browser. Now, I want to execute this script on `emulator` or mobile device. I have tried to execute it by many ways but not get the success.

```
WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();
```

**Throwing exception**

> *Unable to start session Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.*

If any one any idea on this please help me. I also get to know that new selenium not require AndroidDriver. Please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using `Selendroid`?

The same selenium script will work fine for android devices/emulators as well. But as we have a `chromedriverserver` for Chrome browser - you need to download the Selendroid jars, download the Android SDK, run the Selendroid server etc.

Follow the instructions  [here](http://selendroid.io/setup.html)

**EDIT :**

```
        SelendroidLauncher selendroidServer = null;
        WebDriver driver = null;


        SelendroidConfiguration config = new SelendroidConfiguration();

        selendroidServer = new SelendroidLauncher(config);
        selendroidServer.lauchSelendroid();

        SelendroidCapabilities sc = new SelendroidCapabilities();
        sc.setBrowserName("android");
        sc.setPlatform(Platform.ANDROID);
        sc.setSerial("015d24a8394cAAAA");  //serial id of the device


        driver = new SelendroidDriver(sc);
        driver.get("http://m.ebay.de");
```

Comment: I am not using selendroid. In selenium web driver 2.31 version we have androiddriver() which use to execute the script on mobile but now in 2.40+ version androiddriver get omited and it stop working. There should be replacement for androiddriver.

Comment: @itin, I agree. Even then, it did not work out of the box. You had to download and setup android sdk & run the androidserver to connect to the real devices. But AndroidDriver got deprecated in later versions. Selendroid is the replacement for android now.  http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: so Selendroid will be used for native app and web application in android both..? As per me it is for native app <14API...

Comment: for both. I am using selendroid for web based application in my project. It works great so far.

Comment: Can i get some steps, code snipt for both? I am trying to do from last 8hr and not able to launch the application. I have done this so far: installed the webdriver in emulator, for native installed the app, setup the selendroid and it is starting successfully... but what after that?  SelendroidCapabilities capa = new SelendroidCapabilities("<appId>");
WebDriver driver = new SelendroidDriver(capa); This will launch the native app [I hope] but what about web site?  Please help

Comment: Check the edit. I am not testing a native app (But selendroid should support this as well). Mine is a simple web based application. If you had setup everything correctly - above code should work fine. Or provide the exception you face.

Comment: SEVERE: Error occurred while building server: io.selendroid.exceptions.SelendroidException: Command 'aapt' was not found inside the Android SDK. Please update to the latest development tools and try again.  even i have given the path of aapt in enviroment varioable

Comment: I think i have seen this!! have you set the environment variables? something like this...ANDROID_HOME=C:\androidsdk\sdk     & updated the Path variables to C:\androidsdk\sdk\tools;C:\androidsdk\sdk\platform-tools;C:\androidsdk\sdk\build-tools;

Comment: aapt should be there under build tools in a folder like 19.0.1.  and restart might help. let me know.

Comment: yes restart solved the issue.... but now Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at io.selendroid.server.model.DeviceStore.findAndroidDevice(DeviceStore  .java:219)  I gave seriel id like this sc.setSerial("emulator-5554")

Comment: yes and i execute following: java -jar D:\selendroid-standalone-0.10.0-with-dependencies.jar -app "D:\S.apk"

Comment: it shows List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device

Comment: sc..setEmulator(true);  did u do this?   what does it give? http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status    (as per ur port)

Comment: Hi do we need to executed selendroid-standalone  ? i was running with apk that was wrong but still it is not working ...{"appId":"io.selendroid.androiddriver:0.10.0","mainActivity":"io.selendroid.androiddriver.WebViewActivity","basePackage":"io.selendroid.androiddriver"}],"os":{"arch":"amd64","name":"Windows 7","version":"6.1"},"build":{"browserName":"selendroid"

Comment: after removing  sc.setPlatform(Platform.ANDROID);
         sc.setSerial("1234");  it works Thanks a lot for your all help.

Comment: glad that u made it work finally.. ).. I know the setup would be annoying for the first time!